# Find on meteor client don't work

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to do a pretty basic example using meteor js.
In my lib folder (shared by client and server) i have the following code

```
if (typeof hair === 'undefined') {
    hair = {};
}
if (!hair.dao) {
    hair.dao = {};
}

hair.dao.store = (function() {
    return new Meteor.Collection('store');
})();
```

In folder server/libs i have this code

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(hair.dao.store.find().fetch());
});
```

(Which  log one element)

In my client/libs folder i have this code

```
var cursorStores;
cursorStores = hair.dao.store.find();
console.log(cursorStores.fetch());
```

(Which logs no element)

It used to work, but now it stops.

Just to be clear i'm running on windows, and i removed and added again the autopublish package.

Comment: Hmm, looks like on every call of hair.dao.store your are return new Collection, try make collection one time and return cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I think find needs to take an argument. See http://docs.meteor.com/#find

If you are wanting the first element there are other ways of getting it. http://docs.meteor.com/

Try find({}) with empty curly braces

Answer (score 1):

The data probably hasn't reached the client yet when you do that find. Try wrapping those 3 lines of client code in a Deps.autorun